# Websphere liberty add prefix to context roots mentioned in ear/application.xml

Tags: websphere-liberty

We are using websphere liberty 8.5.5.9. I want to know is there any way we can override/add a custom prefix to all web applications packed in an ear?

I don't want to do it at application.xml level. Instead I want to do it at server.xml level. Is there any way?

For example if my ear contains two war modules, whose context roots are sample1, sample2. The final context roots after the prefix should look like example/sample1, example/sample2.

Comment: Can anyone please help me. BTW, this is needed for elastic load balancing

Comment: Hmm... I didn't read your question carefully, sorry.   You asked to adjust all WARs within an EAR, not all WARs within a given server.xml.    I'll delete that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in 8.5.5.9, but is possible in the current beta (February 2017.) As of that level, you can specify in server.xml the extensions configuration that would normally appear in the ibm-web-ext.xml file inside the war file. The configuration would look something like:

```
<application location="myEar.ear">
 <web-ext moduleName="myWar1.war" context-root="sample1"/>
 <web-ext moduleName="myWar2.war" context-root="sample2"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

On WebSphere Liberty, 
I do not think there is a way to get context root working (by defining in server.xml) for web modules which are part of ear file. But you can define context root for web modules as follows:

You can define the context-root for ear file too but it is ignored.

*CWWKZ0126W: The {0} context root value that is specified on the {1} application has no effect.
    Explanation The context-root property is not valid for an enterprise application. The value will not be used for any web modules contained within the enterprise application.*

More details at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dep_war.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5