# How can I set the context root in Liberty using server configuration (server.xml) for my EAR-packaged WARs?

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

I tried to set my context root with the value **"new-ctx"** in Liberty server config:

#### server.xml

```xml
<application id="my-ear" location="my-ear.ear" name="my-ear" context-root="new-ctx"/>
```

This was intended to override the setting in my EAR-level pom, which uses maven-ear-plugin to generate an application.xml with context root **"old-ctx"** for my WAR:

#### pom.xml (EAR)

```xml
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>io.openliberty.guides</groupId>
                            <artifactId>guide-maven-multimodules-war</artifactId>
                            <uri>my.war</uri>
                            <contextRoot>old-ctx</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However this didn't work, I still see 'old-ctx':

```
 [INFO] [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://<host>:9080/old-ctx/
```

Comment: **NOTE:**  The core of the answer is actually captured in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550629/websphere-liberty-add-prefix-to-context-roots-mentioned-in-ear-application-xml), but my new question comes to this answer from a different enough angle that a new question is worth it, and it's not just a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Add a `<web-ext>` element with a `context-root` attribute as a child element of `<application>`, e.g.:

#### server.xml

```xml
<application id="my-ear"  location="my-ear.ear"  name="my-ear">
    <web-ext moduleName="my.war" context-root="new-ctx"/>
</application>
```

OR, (using `<enterpriseApplication>` instead of `<application>`)

```xml
<enterpriseApplication id="my-ear"  location="my-ear.ear"  name="my-ear">
    <web-ext moduleName="my.war" context-root="new-ctx"/>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

#### NOTE:

The `moduleName` attribute of `<web-ext>` should match the `<web-uri>` element value (contents) in **application.xml**.

E.g. in my example (though all details are not shown), this **application.xml** value originates from the                             `<uri>my.war</uri>` element value within the particular `<webModule>` configured via the maven-ear-plugin configuration (since this plugin generates the application.xml).

### EXPLANATION

The `context-root` attribute of the `<application>` is not really used when the `<application>` location points to an EAR.  This `<application>` element has the ability to be used to configure either an EAR or a WAR, and the `context-root` can be used when configuring a WAR.

When configuring an EAR, however, the context root needs to be set on the level of the individual WAR(s) within the EAR, and so something like the `<web-ext>` child element must be used.